# Laravel4 redirect withInput() fails to populate fields

Tags: php, laravel-4

When I redirect to the page it fails to populate the input fields.

```
if ($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('books/create')->with('message_warning','<strong>Warning!</strong> some input is not valid.')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }else{
            $book->save();
            return Redirect::action('BooksController@index')->with('message_success','<strong>Awesome!</strong>Your book has been successfully added.');
        }
```

`Input::old()` works on redirection.

**Form Excerpt**

```
{{  Form::open(array('action' => 'BooksController@store', 'method' => 'post', 'role'=> 'form')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Name of awesome book?">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the value using the old input.

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ Input::old('title') }}">
```

Comment: ahh ofcourse! was following a tutorial which failed to show that. Will accept answer when I can.